# Remote Webdriver Chrome throws a "path to the driver executable" error

Tags: c#, webdriver, remotewebdriver

Hi when i use the following code

```
IWebDriver _webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
                DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

I get the follwing error

> System.InvalidOperationException : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
>   TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>      at Testframework.Browser.RemoteGoto(String browser, String url) in Browser.cs: line 86
>      at Testframework.CommonAction.RemoteBrowser(String browser) in CommonAction.cs: line 70
>      at Test.RegistrationTest.InvalidRegistrationTest(String browser, String username, String password, String confirmPassword, String securityQuestion, String securityAnswer, String errorMessageText, String firstname, String lastname) in RegistrationTest.cs: line 50
>   --TearDown
>      at Testframework.CommonAction.CaptureScreen(String fileName) in CommonAction.cs: line 121
>      at Test.RegistrationTest.SnapshotOnFailure() in RegistrationTest.cs: line 590

Answer (score 4):

The clue really is in the error.

Chrome should be installed on the system where the tests are either running on or being pointed to.

Take a step back, look at the documentation:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Also, if Chrome is installed in a peculiar place, you'll need to point Selenium to it's location. Again, this is explained in the documentation.

In C#:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.binary", this.binaryLocation);
```

or:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = "pathtogooglechrome";
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
```

Comment: Hi , i am able to find only java examples , can you tell me how to set the path of the chrome in C# webdriver remote , since i am not able to find a equivalent in C#q

Comment: Thank u , This is the path i set options.BinaryLocation = @"..\RequiredFiles\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\chromedriver.exe"; i am getting the following error "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property"

Comment: Tried this System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver",@"/path/to/where/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe") which C# equivalent java System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/where/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe"); which did not work

Comment: If you use the ChromeDriver directly (look at the documentation), does it launch Chrome OK?

Comment: Yes when i do this "ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverpath)" it works but i am not able to set the chromedriverpath in the remote webdriver.I have no idea why

Answer (score 4):

Instead of changing the code you can have other way round.

Download the chrome driver and set the **`PATH`** environment variable pointing to the directory where the chromedriver.exe is present.

Restart your IDE / Command console and run the tests. It works!!!

Comment: Thank u is there any other way other than setting it up as environment variable . i also found this solution setting up the chromedriver path when launching the console(java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\example\chromedriver.exe  -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar). I want to avoid this solution as much as possible and set the path in code so the code remains portable :)

Comment: @AnandS To maintain the code as portable it's better if we had not hardcoded the location of the driver. I prefer setting path, as the developed tests can be ported on to any machine and can be used just by setting the PATH

Comment: Thank u , I am very curious to know why when i use this System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver",@"/path/to/w‌​here/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe") the chromedriver.exe is not getting set a environmental variable