# Safari Wabdriver

Tags: c#, safari, webdriver, screenshot

I'm using C# and I'm trying to use Safari WebDriver for capturing web pages' screenshots from Safari browsers,
I was facing the following exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

this method is for taking screenshots

```
public static void TakeScreenShot(IWebDriver WD, string url, string path)
    {
        WD.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        WD.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);


        WD.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        ITakesScreenshot screenShotDriver = WD as ITakesScreenshot;
        Screenshot screenshot = screenShotDriver.GetScreenshot();
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(path, ImageFormat.Png);

        WD.Quit();
    }
```

How should I fix that?

Comment: We'll need a stack trace to be able to help you out, where's the null reference coming from (what line)?

Comment: the error was at this line 
"Screenshot screenshot = screenShotDriver.GetScreenshot();"
And in an other class I created a new SafariDriver object. 
by the way the code was working perfectly with other webbrowser (FF and IE)

Comment: Then that error is telling you that your Safari `IWebDriver` cannot be cast to that `ITakesScreenshot` interface. There is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4750) open for this, but the updates on the issue make it seem like this should be working. What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: the version is 2.20.0

Comment: Perhaps that was/is still an issue in that version, I know nothing about Selenium. That same issue page lists a [workaround](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#taking-a-screenshot): creating your own wrapper class.

Comment: ah sorry the current version is 2.40 I made a mistake

Comment: Any help on this please ? I'm using selenium 2.40 and still can't figure out what happened.
If it's a known issue, could you provide me with another solution please?

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote Webdriver Chrome throws a "path to the driver executable" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199545/remote-webdriver-chrome-throws-a-path-to-the-driver-executable-error)